# Want to copy data from my website to fields in another website

Tags: php, forms, web, external

I have a table with data on my website and I have to enter the data into input controls on another website (which I do not own) on a regular basis. Is there a way to pre-fill these inputs on the external website with data from my website without manually entering it? My website runs on PHP and the other website is written in ASP.

Comment: you would need to have access to change the other website otherwise no there isn't really any way to do it.

Comment: by table do you mean a db table, or html table? because you could just connect to the database if that was the case.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you can't modify an other webpage.

If you lucky you can pass some parameters to the page, but only if the page has implemented this:

```
link_to_page?datafield=contents
```

**Or use Bookmarklets**

Another way is to use a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet). Basicly you inject javascript into the page, load you content and insert it into the form.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to "manipulate" a foreign page is within your browser using tools like "[Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)" which is a Firefox Addon. It uses Javascript to edit a page in the browser. It should be possible to fill out a form with it if you hard-code the needed values so it doesn't really fulfill all your needs...

Answer (score 1):

If the other website is not protected (captchas, CSFR tokens, etc.) you could just create a script php to [send post messages using curl](http://www.askapache.com/php/sending-post-form-data-php-curl.html) inside a loop... but ehem... the other website might not like that and they might consider it as an attack :P..

of course, in this case you wont be using a browser, the info will be sent between servers.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for all the answers so far, I will work through it and reply. An example of the page I want to fill in is 

http://www.next.co.uk/quickshop.asp    

I want to fill in the input columns for the item codes like 465-392-X44 on the page with values in my database which I also display in a table on my website.